# How do I override an inherited value in a web.config?

Tags: web-config

Suppose I have in a web app's root web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="TestKey" value="TestValue0" />
    ...
```

How do I override that value in a sub folder of the same website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply remove it and add it again:

```
<appSettings>
    <remove key="TestKey" />
    <add key="TestKey" value="TestValue0" />
    ...
```